# Previous array data gets printed to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

this is related to the code from my previous question, but this new problem is related to printing array data into a string, which then is passed on to the text on my page

My page "rolls" genetic data, which is presented as gene abbreviations. Under the abbreviations, i want to list the gene names. What happens is that the array values from a previous "roll" gets printed underneath a new roll, meaning that the array that contains the gene names is always one "roll" behind.

i suspect it has to do with the fact that im using $.getJSON, but I'm not sure how to use the current data instead of the previous data.

here is what my code for this part looks like:

```
$.getJSON('genes.json', function(data){
            $.each(data.gCommon, function(i, g) {
              if(genoArray.includes(g.rec) || genoArray.includes(g.dom)){
              phenoArray.push(g.phen);
            }
        });
        getPheno(phenoArray);
    });

function getPheno(phenoArray){
console.log(genoArray);
console.log(phenoArray);
$phenoString = phenoArray.join(", ");
}

$babyGenes = genoArray.join("/");
  if(genoArray.length > 1){
    $babyPheno = $phenoString.replace(/("[^"]+"|\w+)$/, "and $1");
  } else {
    $babyPheno = $phenoString;
  }

  console.log("Baby: " + $babyGenes);
  console.log("Pheno: " + $babyPheno);
```

any advice helps, thanks in advance!!

Comment: Whats your expected result?

Comment: `$.getJSON()` is asynchronous so you are creating `$babyGenes` before `getPheno()` ever gets called

Comment: @GetSet id like for it to read the 'genes', pull the corresponding gene names from the json, and then output it all together

Comment: @charlietfl is there a way to have getPheno() be current with $babyGenes? ive been looking, but a lot of proposed solutions are kinda specific to the other questions that they answer :(

Comment: Process it after getPheno gets called. Could wrap it in a function and call that in the getJSON after you make the getPheno call something like `getPheno(); doBabyGenes()`

Comment: @charlietfl that kinda worked! it no longer randomizes the results (three 'babies' all get the exact same genetics now) but thats a problem for later, and it is printing the current data as intended :)
thanks!